# How come these are distributive lattices?

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

[On Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice)  I can see examples of distributive lattices. But I don't get how they are distributive. To my eyes, they are not even modular.

[image: Distributive lattices?]

E.g. how does it fulfill the modular property of

$$(x \wedge y <: x) \wedge (x \wedge y <: y) \Leftrightarrow (x <: x \vee y) \wedge (y <: x \vee y)$$?

E.g. if I take $b, d$ in the left lattice, where $c$ is their meet, but they are not covered by their join (it's $a$). Or $b,d$ in the right lattice, where again $c$ is their meet, they are not covered by their join either (because it's $d$)

Comment: Where on Wikipedia?

Comment: The left lattice is the direct product of a $3$-element chain and a $2$-element chain. By the way, the line between $b$ and $c$ is unnecessary.

Comment: What is the notation $\lt:$ supposed to mean?

Comment: @bof Covering relation.

Comment: @bof OK, does that mean, that in the right lattice, the lines $c \le d$, $c \le e$, and $b \le a$ are just as unnecessary?

Comment: In diagrams of finite lattices, it is customary to show only the covering relations. Drawing those extra lines makes the picture confusing.

Comment: In the left lattice $d$ is not covered by $a,$ but neither is $c$ covered by $b.$

Comment: Maybe the point of the diagrams is to show that a subset of a distributive lattice, with the inherited partial order, isn't necessarily a distributive lattice - even if it does happen to form a lattice?  e.g. the left has a pentagon as the solid lines, and the right has the other prototypical countexample as the solid lines.  (With the point being that these subsets aren't actually sublattices.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler Exactly this is the point, which is explained at the Wikipedia page